# Promise method undefined (Angularjs with typescript)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, promise

I have a problem.

I am using Angularjs and Typescript in my project.

My problem is that when I call the getResult() method the browser gives an undefined error.

How can I solve this problem ?

I call getResult() method :

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResult' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5vHR.jpg)

[image]

My Controller :

```
module MyApp {

class myModalCtrl {
    static $inject = ['IOService', '$interval'];

    public modalStatus: boolean;
    public promise: any;

    constructor(private IOService: IOService, private $interval: ng.IIntervalService) {}

    init() {
        this.modalStatus = false;
        this.cancel();
        this.promise = this.$interval(this.listenResult, 3000);
    }

    getResult() {
        return this.IOService.request({
            url: 'token/validatetoken',
            data: {},
            disableSpinner: true
        }).then((res) => {
            if (angular.isUndefined(res.user)) return false;
            else return true;
        });
    }

    listenResult() {
        this.getResult().then(res => {
            if (res) this.openModal();
        });
    }

    cancel() {
        this.$interval.cancel(this.promise);
    }

    openModal() {
        this.cancel();
        this.modalStatus = true;
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.cancel();
        this.promise = this.$interval(this.listenResult, 3000);
        this.modalStatus = false;
    }



}

app.controller('myModalCtrl', myModalCtrl);}
```

Comment: Share your controller code, cant answer from the code you have provided

Comment: I shared the controller.

Comment: Where does the error occur? is it in `listenResult`?

Comment: Yes, error accour in listenResult()

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResult' of undefined at listenResult()

Comment: This question is being asked every other day. Replace `this.$interval(this.listenResult, 3000)` by `this.$interval(() => this.listenResult(), 3000)`, or by `this.$interval(this.listenResult.bind(this), 3000)`.

Comment: Thank you, @JBNizet . Problem is solved. 

Could you perhaps explain what your code does?

Comment: It binds themethod to this, either explicitly (bind(this)), or by using an arrow function.